# Dúvida sobre chave estrangeira hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xgWF.png)

A tabela diary_place está sendo criada com 2 campo do user_id, eu quero que seja somente um user_id referenciado como chave estrangeira para as tabelas diary e place.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero que o resultado seja igual o da segunda imagem.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name ="diary_place",
           joinColumns = { 
                          @JoinColumn(name = "diary_id", referencedColumnName="id"), 
                          @JoinColumn(name = "d_user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id" ) 
                         },                    
           inverseJoinColumns = { 
                                 @JoinColumn(name = "place_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false), 
                                 @JoinColumn(name = "p_user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id") 
                                },
           foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_diary"),
           inverseForeignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_place")
          )
private List <Place> places;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando você tem duas tabelas com relacionamento muitos-pra-muitos tem que ter uma tabela no meio. É por isso que tem a diary_place. E pra manter a consistência dos dados usa-se as duas chaves estrangeiras como está na imagem. Você pode remover uma chave e usar a outra chave pra ligar as duas tabelas (d_user_id por ex), mas aí dará inconsistência nos dados com certeza.

Comment: Quero que fique igual na imagem que acabei de adicionar, somente com um campo referente ao id do usuario. Desta forma não vai deixar brecha para inconsistência.

Comment: Bom, foi o que eu te falei então. ambas as tabelas se ligando a uma mesma chave estrangeira na tabela do meio. Se estiver em conformidade com a lógica do seu negócio, então está correto.